# Mute Audio from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, mute

I was sitting here wondering if it's possible to write a greasemonkey script that would detect sites like payperclick and mute the audio so the ad isn't heard.

I realize that I could accomplish the same thing in a better fashion by simply removing the ad text through a greasemonkey script but for purposes of curiousity, I wondered if you can disable the audio through javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way **I** can see this being possible is if:

1)the ad has its own "mute button" which called a javascript function...in which case you could just call that function yourself.

2) The plugin the ad is using for audio has a javascript API (same as 1)

3) IE only: some bizarre IE ActiveX thing that could probably do it...by accessing stuff that it probably shouldn't.

All of these I consider extremely doubtful

Any other possibility would be too low level for javascript to have access to (or at least I seriously hope that is the case). A browser by itself has no volume controls....all multimedia are done by plugins.

Comment: lol @ #3.  ActiveX was probably one of Microsoft's worst decisions security-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Other than completely stripping the <embed> element, it's a no-go; JavaScript simply doesn't have the power to access the volume controls of Flash media... yet. : )

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the autostart attribute on the `embed` element or setting it to false.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the aswer, pass by control the browser.... maybe something that generat some incompatility in some browsers but not hack, and only controlling the browser or keyboard by user choice